# how to make image view fit the image width and height

Tags: android, imageview

[image]

I am new to android development. I have a **IMAGE VIEW** in that image I am retrieving image from database (Firebase). What is my problem is  ... The **IMAGE** does not fits the image view .. Dslr camera photos fits ..but 
on phone camera photo it does not fits **It does not look nice** I want image view to expand or fits the image according to image width and height the ...and  max height should be around 600dp height

I used this code

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

Comment: can you please post full imageview xml code.

Comment: I have edited please see

Comment: please check my below answer.

Comment: no it does not solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

set `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

or

```
                         int oldWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
                        int oldHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
                        double aspectRatio = ((double) oldWidth / (double) oldHeight);
                        DisplayMetrics display = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                        int width = (int) ((display.widthPixels) * 0.6);
                        int height = (int) (width / aspectRatio);
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
                        Imageview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this parameter:  `android:scaleType="centerInside"`

Answer (score 0):

set these attributes:

```
android:layout_width="600dp"
android:layout_height="600dp"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

change the dimensions as you like  
if you use `android:scaleType="centerInside"` then the image if it is smaller than the ImageView will retain its size.

Comment: bro..I used this but ..I the dslr photo which as less height gets effected

Comment: Then use centerInside

Comment: Read this (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType). You can choose what is right for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="600dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/yourimage"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use it in your XML file in ImageeView it's one properties to solve your problem android:scaleType="fitXY" or "centerInside" or "centerCrop"